# Numpy compare 2 array shape, if different, append 0 to match shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am comparing 2 numpy arrays, and want to add them together. but, before doing so, i need to make sure they are the same size. If the size are not same, then take the smaller sized one and fill the last rows with zero to match the shape. 
Both array have 16 columns and N rows. I am assuming it should be pretty straight forward, but I can't get my head around it. So far I am able to compare the 2 array shape.

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import sys
data = np.genfromtxt('./test1.csv', dtype=float, delimiter=',')
data_sys = np.genfromtxt('./test2.csv', dtype=float, delimiter=',')   
print data.shape
print data_sys.shape
if data.shape != data_sys.shape:
        print "we have an error"
```

This is the output I got:

```
=============New file.csv============
(603, 16)
(604, 16)
we have an error
```

I want the fill the last row of "data" array with 0 so that I can add the 2 arrays.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `vstack(array1, array2)` from numpy which stacks arrays vertically. For example:

```
A = np.random.randint(2, size = (2, 16))
B = np.random.randint(2, size = (5, 16))

print A.shape
print B.shape
if A.shape[0] < B.shape[0]:
    A = np.vstack((A, np.zeros((B.shape[0] - A.shape[0], 16))))
elif A.shape[0] > B.shape[0]:
    B = np.vstack((B, np.zeros((A.shape[0] - B.shape[0], 16)))) 

print A.shape   
print A
```

In your case:

```
if data.shape[0] < data_sys.shape[0]:
    data = np.vstack((data, np.zeros((data_sys.shape[0] - data.shape[0], 16))))
elif data.shape[0] > data_sys.shape[0]:
    data_sys = np.vstack((data_sys, np.zeros((data.shape[0] - data_sys.shape[0], 16))))
```

I assume that your matrices have always the same number of columns, if not you can similarly use `hstack` to stack them horizontally.

Comment: I used vstack and hstack as AniaG suggested to match two different matrices with different sizes. These are the result of masking small regions on a 2D image and both share a common center. I simply performed vstack and hstack twice in order to add the missing values after and before.

Answer (score 2):

If you have only two files, and their shapes differ in just the 0th dimension, a simple check and copy is probably easiest, though it lacks generality:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt('./test1.csv', dtype=float, delimiter=',')
data_sys = np.genfromtxt('./test2.csv', dtype=float, delimiter=',')   

fill_value = 0 # could be np.nan or something else instead

if data.shape[0]>data_sys.shape[0]:
    temp = data_sys
    data_sys = np.ones(data.shape)*fill_value
    data_sys[:temp.shape[0],:] = temp
elif data.shape[0]<data_sys.shape[0]:
    temp = data
    data = np.ones(data_sys.shape)*fill_value
    data[:temp.shape[0],:] = temp

print 'Using conditional:'
print data.shape
print data_sys.shape
if data.shape != data_sys.shape:
        print "we have an error"
```

A much more general solution is a custom class--overkill for your two files but much easier if you have lots of files to handle. The basic idea is that static class variables `sx` and `sy` keep track of the largest widths and heights, and are used when `get_data` is called, to output a standard shape array. This is pre-filled with your desired fill value, and the actual data from the corresponding file are copied into the upper left corner of the standard shape array:

```
import numpy as np

class IsomorphicArray:

    sy = 0 # static class variable
    sx = 0 # static class variable
    fill_value = 0.0

    def __init__(self,csv_filename):
        self.data = np.genfromtxt(csv_filename,dtype=float,delimiter=',')
        self.instance_sy,self.instance_sx = self.data.shape
        if self.instance_sy>IsomorphicArray.sy:
            IsomorphicArray.sy = self.instance_sy
        if self.instance_sx>IsomorphicArray.sx:
            IsomorphicArray.sx = self.instance_sx

    def get_data(self):
        out = np.ones((IsomorphicArray.sy,IsomorphicArray.sx))*self.fill_value
        out[:self.instance_sy,:self.instance_sx] = self.data
        return out

isomorphic_array_list = []

for filename in ['./test1.csv','./test2.csv']:
    isomorphic_array_list.append(IsomorphicArray(filename))

numpy_array_list = []

for isomorphic_array in isomorphic_array_list:
    numpy_array_list.append(isomorphic_array.get_data())


print 'Using custom class:'
for numpy_array in numpy_array_list:
    print numpy_array.shape
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both arrays have 16 columns

```
len1=len(data)
len2=len(data_sys)
if len1<len2:
  data=np.append(data, np.zeros((len2-len1, 16)),axis=0)
elif len2<len1:
  data_sys=np.append(data_sys, np.zeros((len1-len2, 16)),axis=0)
print data.shape
print data_sys.shape
if data.shape != data_sys.shape:
  print "we have an error"
else:
  print "we r good"
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy provides an append function to add values to an array: [see here for details](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html). In multi-dimensional arrays you can define how the values should be added. As you have already the information which of your arrays is the smaller one, just add the desired number of zeroes with creating a zero filled array first by [numpy.zeroes](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) and then append it to your target array.

It might be necessary to [flatten](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) your array first and then to [reshape](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) it.

Comment: I am using this following code:
x = data.shape[0]
 y = data_sys.shape[0]
 if x < y:
  print "User.csv have less rows"
  diff = y - x
  zero_array = np.zeros(diff,16)
  data = np.append(data,zero_array)
  print data.shape

But getting the following error:

"User.csv have less rows
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "combine_usr_sys.py", line 33, in <module>
    zero_array = np.zeros(diff,16)
TypeError: data type not understood"

Comment: np.zeros(diff, 16) seems odd. diff is the difference, so much I've understood. But what is '16' standing for. The function requires a dtype as second argument. That is either a numpy.intxx (xx = 8, 32, 64, ...) or a float argument.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation. Two arrays of sizes mask_in:(n1,m1) and mask_ot:(n2,m2)that were generated through a mask of a 2D image of size (N,M) where A2 is larger than A1 and both share a common center (X0,Y0). I followed the approach suggested by @AniaG using vstack and hstack. I simply obtained the shapes of both arrays, size difference and finally account the number of missing elements at both ends.
Here is what I got:

```
mask_in = np.random.randint(2, size = (2, 8))
mask_ot = np.random.randint(2, size = (6, 16))
mask_in_amp = mask_in

dif_row = mask_ot.shape[0]-mask_in_amp.shape[0]
dif_col = mask_ot.shape[1]-mask_in_amp.shape[1]

complete_row = dif_row / 2
complete_col = dif_col / 2

mask_in_amp = np.vstack((mask_in_amp, np.zeros((complete_row, mask_in_amp.shape[1]))))
mask_in_amp = np.vstack((np.zeros((complete_row, mask_in_amp.data.shape[1])), mask_in_amp))

mask_in_amp = np.hstack((mask_in_amp, np.zeros((mask_in_amp.shape[0],complete_col))))
mask_in_amp = np.hstack((np.zeros((mask_in_amp.shape[0],complete_col)), mask_in_amp))
```

Answer (score -2):

If you don't care about the **exact** shapes of two arrays you can also do the following:

```
if data.size == datasys.size:
    print ('arrays have the same number of elements, and possibly shape')
else:
    print ('arrays do not have the same shape for sure')
```